# Significance of Categorical variables in regression in R - against each other

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance

Good afternoon,
I need help in intpretting the significance results when performing a linear regression with a categorical interaction.  I'm running this analysis in R.

The question is whether I can use qsec as an explantory variable in the below model given that one of the categorical variables is not significantly different to the other.

Model & Outputs

```
lm(mpg~qsec+am+qsec*am, data=mtcars)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  -9.0099     8.2179  -1.096  0.28226   
qsec          1.4385     0.4500   3.197  0.00343 **
am1         -14.5107    12.4812  -1.163  0.25481   
qsec:am1      1.3214     0.7017   1.883  0.07012 .
```

The second coefficient is not statistical significant - though only just with a p value of 0.07.
Does this mean that I should look for another explanatory variable?

When I run the regression on one of the values - am1 - alone, then it is still significantly different to zero.  As is am0 from the above results.

When I look at the data, the slope appears significantly different so I think I can use it however the understanding of the theory says no - which is frustrating.  I would add my plot to highlight my point but I'm struggling to load it.

I hope this isn't a stupid question to ask...I've found some good explanations of categorical variables in general, however nothing that tells me how I should interpret this secondary variable.

James

** edit changed data to be qsec per question below

Comment: Is "data" supposed to be qsec in the list of coefficients?

Comment: Sorry yes.  I was playing around with variables to see what was the best to do a model on and rather than change out the variable everytime for all my code, I just made it equal data.  Will change it now.

Comment: What types of variables are qsec and am? Continuous? Categorical?

Comment: qsec is continuous and am is categorical

Comment: Are you sure that the assumptions for a linear model hold for this dataset? If it is, then without looking at anything else I would say you have to exclude am1, and re-run the fitting without it to see whether the interaction term is significant. I would also examine the binning of am1 - are there levels of that variable that are not credible on a stand-alone basis, and need to be combined with other levels?

Answer (score 1):

This is an area where exploring the data and your results should help guide your conclusions. Remember that "statistical significance" is not the end-all of a conclusion.  A good analysis will help the data tell it's own story, and relying on significance is only looking at part of the story.  First, let's plot our data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am, 0:1, c("Automatic", "Manual"))

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = qsec,
           y = mpg,
           colour = am)) + 
  geom_point()
```

You should seem some pretty clear trends in these data (trends this clear are kind of rare).  The Manual transmissions tend to have higher mpg, and in general, higher `qsec` (quarter mile time) tracks with higher `mpg`.

When we fit the "plain" model, our results give objective evidence to those suspicions:

```
#* Fit the model without the interaction
fit0 <- lm(mpg ~ qsec + am, data = mtcars)
summary(fit0)
```

As you've noticed, that evidence isn't as simple to see once we include the interaction term:

```
#* Fit the model with the interaction
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ qsec * am, data = mtcars)
summary(fit1)
```

So what happened?  The interaction term is "modifying" the effect of `qsec` on `mpg` differently for manual transmissions than it is for automatic transmissions.  In other words, the plain model assumes that the slopes are identical in both groups, while the interaction model accepts the possibility that the slopes are different.  This can be visualized in the following figure:

```
new_data <- expand.grid(qsec = seq(min(mtcars$qsec), 
                                       max(mtcars$qsec), 
                                   length.out = 1000),
                        am = c("Automatic", "Manual")) %>%
  mutate(pred_plain = predict(fit0, newdata = .),
         pred_interaction = predict(fit1, newdata = .)) %>%
  gather(model, pred,
         pred_plain, pred_interaction) %>%
  mutate(model = gsub("pred_", "", model))

ggplot(new_data,
       aes(x = qsec,
           y = pred,
           colour = am)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ylab("Predicted mpg") + 
  xlab("Quarter Mile Time (qsec)") + 
  facet_grid(model ~ .)
```

From the figure, we see a pretty clear indication that the increase in `mpg` as `qsec` increases is greater in the manual transmission than the automatic transmission.

One of the more difficult questions to answer, based on our results so far, is whether or not the transmission as a significant effect in this model.  Recall from the summary of `fit1` that the coefficient for `am` is not statistically significant, but it was in `fit0`, and the predicted values suggest that maybe it has a meaningful impact.  In these situations, it's important to remember that you shouldn't interpret a main effect without its accompanying interaction effects.  How to interpret them together is a challenging topic, and I'm not sure I'm well qualified to address it.  But I will point out that the model summary may not be the best place to look as it focuses on the coefficients, not necessarily the variables.  Instead, take a look at the ANOVA summary

```
anova(fit1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mpg
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
qsec       1 197.39  197.39 17.6583 0.0002438 ***
am         1 576.02  576.02 51.5297 8.203e-08 ***
qsec:am    1  39.64   39.64  3.5458 0.0701227 .  
Residuals 28 313.00   11.18                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This summary gives a better overview of how "impactful" each variable is, as opposed to just the regression coefficients.  It suggests that `qsec` and `am` are both related to the change in response, even in the presence of the interaction.

The other difficult question to answer is if the interaction is worth keeping in the model.  This is like asking if the interaction modified the slopes enough to make us believe that they really aren't parallel.  I believe there are a number of ways to make this decision, and honestly, ask me on a different day and I may give you a different answer.  Some people say to remove interactions if they are not statistically significant, but today I say to keep them if they show a p-value less than 0.10 because I'd prefer to err on the side of a slightly more complex model than to over simplify the model.  But the decision may involve as much experience and subject matter knowledge as it does objective science.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand tha value in the significance test but also agree in the pragmatic approach.  Using am as basis for the model may not give the best model, however the question I need to answer is what impact transmission difference gives.  So it needs to be there in my view.

Comment: @Benjamin - how did you know so much about the project without him saying so?

Comment: I came across this question from Stack Exchange with the [r] tag.  So I already knew the code was R, and the `mtcars` data set is a sample data set that ships in R.  I probably should have helped clarify that, but if you were to assume the question was R based, it isn't a big leap to figure out what the data are.  Sorry for not clarifying.